# How to import excel data in to playframework

Tags: playframework-2.4

I am new to play framework, please provide any example to import excel data into play framework and display the data...i am using play 2.x

Answer (score 0):

First you need to upload the Excel file.  You don't say if you're using Java or Scala so I'll just link to the docs for both:

- Java: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaFileUpload
- Scala: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaFileUpload

Once you have the file, you can then use an off-the-shelf library such as JExcelApi (http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) or Apache POI (https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) to process the data.

Binding the content of the Excel file to some local data structure - if you have a known data definition, you can create classes to model the data (let's call this `MyModelClass` for this example).  If it's arbitrary data, you can use one LinkedHashMap (which will preserve insertion order) per line to store the data.

This will give you either a `List<MyModelClass>` or a `List<Map>`.  To display the data, you can then write a template to iterate over the list and display each row.  For `MyModelClass`, you could hard-code the label; for the `Map`, the labels can be taken from the keys in the map.

Without seeing what you've already done, and in which language, it's hard to add extra detail at this point.